# Override a property to another type on derived class

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I'm trying to find out a solution for this, but I'm not sure if it's possible or not.

I have a base class, lets say

```
public class A
{
   [XmlAttribute("Date")]
   public DateTime Date {get;set;}
}
```

and a derived class:

```
public class B: A
{
   [XmlAttribute("Date")]
   public new String StringDate {get;set;}
}
```

I have to serialize a Xml.

The value of "Date" on the Xml, is String and in fact it's not a DateTime format string. But I use "A" for many other stuff so I cannot just change it to String without affecting other parts of the program. Sadly it is not an option.

So my idea is to create a derived class "B" who inherit everything of "A" and overrided the property Date to get it fill from the deserialization and then format it to DateTime.

I read about virtual or abstracts but I'm not acquainted with it and don't have any clue about it, if it is the solution maybe someone can guide me on the first steps.

Anyone can help me?

EDIT
XML:

```
<Vorgang Vorgang="HQHT8GTQ">
        <Vertragsbeginn Vertragsbeginn="20140202" />
</Vorgang>
```

Class A:

```
[DataContract(Name = "Vorgang")]
[KnownType(typeof(Vorgang))]
public class Vorgang
{
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public DateTime Vertragsbeginn { get; set; }
}
```

Class B:

```
public class VorgangOverride : UTILMD.Vorgang
{
    private string datestring;

    [XmlAttribute("Vertragsbeginn")]
    public new String Vertragsbeginn {
        get { return datestring; }
        set
        {
            base.Vertragsbeginn = DateUtil.StringToDate(value, EDIEnums.Vertragsbeginn);
            datestring = value;
        } 
    }
}
```

Deserialization method:

```
private static VorgangOverride Deserialize (XmlNode inVorgang)
{
    using (MemoryStream stm = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (StreamWriter stw = new StreamWriter(stm))
        {
            stw.Write(inVorgang.OuterXml);
            stw.Flush();
            stm.Position = 0;

            XmlRootAttribute xRoot = new XmlRootAttribute { ElementName = "Vorgang", IsNullable = true };

            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(VorgangOverride), xRoot);

            VorgangOverride podItem = (VorgangOverride) serializer.Deserialize(stm);

            return podItem;
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Solved using

```
[XmlRoot("Vorgang")]
public class VorgangOverride
{
    public VorgangOverride()
    {

    }
    #region Public Properties

    public string datestring;

    [XmlElement("Vertragsbeginn")]
    public Vertragsbeginn VertragsbeginnAsString { get ; set ;}

    #endregion
}

public class Vertragsbeginn
{

    [XmlAttribute("Vertragsbeginn")]
    public String vertragsbeginn { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you rename the property?

Comment: Yes, I can rename it but will not be difference at all, because the Attribute (update on the question) is the same in both properties and raise an exception during runtime =(

Comment: you are saying that do you want to deserialize an XML to "A" but the Xml have the property DateTime as string (and without DateTime format)?

Comment: Tareq, what I was trying to say is that it probably isn't a good idea to have a variable of the same name with two different types, its going to make your logic everywhere be very confusing and cumbersome. Either make it so that they are the same type or give them two different names

Comment: That's correct @Alexander. The xml contains the date property in a format like "201401161022", it's a string, but the property on "A" is a DateTime and because I cannot just change it I just was wondering if the task was possible to do on a derived class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
[DataContract(Name = "Vorgang")]
[KnownType(typeof(Vorgang))]
public class Vorgang
{
    [XmlIgnore]  // use XmlIgnore instead IgnoreDataMember
    public DateTime Vertragsbeginn { get; set; }
}

// this class map all elements from the xml that you show
[XmlRoot("Vorgang")]  // to map the Xml Vorgang as a VorgangOverride instance
public class VorgangOverride : Vorgang
{
    [XmlAttribute("Vorgang2")]  // to map the Vorgang attribute
    public string VorgangAttribute { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Vertragsbeginn")]  // to map the Vertragsbeginn element
    public Vertragsbeginn VertragsbeginnElement
    {
        get { return _vertragsbeginn; }
        set
        {
            base.Vertragsbeginn = new DateTime();  // here I Assing the correct value to the DateTime property on Vorgan class.
            _vertragsbeginn = value;
        }
    }
    private Vertragsbeginn _vertragsbeginn;
}

// this class is used to map the Vertragsbeginn element
public class Vertragsbeginn
{
    [XmlAttribute("Vertragsbeginn")]  // to map the Vertragsbeginn attriubute on the Vertragsbeginn element
    public string VertragsbeginnAttribute { get; set; }
}
```

later I say:

```
var string xmlContent =
@"<Vorgang Vorgang2=""HQHT8GTQ"">
<Vertragsbeginn Vertragsbeginn=""20140202"" />
</Vorgang>";
        var a = Deserialize<VorgangOverride>(xmlContent);
```

and this is the method to Deserialize:

```
    // method used to deserialize an xml to object
    public static T Deserialize<T>(string xmlContent)
    {
        T result;
        var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        using (TextReader textReader = new StringReader(xmlContent))
        {
            result = ((T)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(textReader));
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Not really, raise an exception saying that the xmlAttribute is already on the base class and I should use another name for the attribute or a new namespace.

Comment: verfica de nuevo que copiaste exactamente el codigo que te puse, porque eso funciona correctamente. (nota que tambien modifique la clase A)

Comment: Si, me faltaba añadir el Ignore, lo he puesto pero me ha saltado otra diferente diciendo que el String '' is not a valid AllXsd-Value

Comment: si pudieras mostrar el contenido del Xml que estas usando? tal vez ahi pueda estar el problema.

Comment: OK. No tienes porque sobreescribir la propiedad 'Vertragsbeginn' en la clase 'VorgangOverride' y la clase 'VorgangOverride' debe tener el atributo [XmlRoot("Vorgang")]. Voy a editar mi respuesta para q veas como debe quedar el codigo.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75942/discussion-between-tareq-b-and-alexander-leyva-caro).

Comment: Edit mi pregunta, creo que tengo una solución que funciona

Comment: @TareqB. la solucion q te propuese funciona correctamente.

Comment: Si, te la marco como aceptada, pero realmente ya lo estoy haciendo con reflexion, debido a que no es solo vertragsbeginn, vienen cientos de valores, y ya hice en su día una clase para serializar correctamente (unas 3000 lineas), pero este formato cambia cada 6 meses y la clase no estaba actualizada (ni la voy a actualizar), de todas formas gracias por tu tiempo.

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to override a property with an other class type.

The reason is Polymorphism. (more information: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152.aspx)

You can cast the class B to class A. Which means the class B must have all the properties and methods class A has, too. But in your case class B would have a String rather than a Date called Date. Which is simply not possible.

Comment: Ok, so is not even possible if I use generic types and virtuals properties?

Comment: Well the first thing i would try before trying to override would be writing a setter that takes a string. e.g. setDate(String date) and convert the string to a DateTime class and set it in that method. Many (de)serializers actually use the setters to set the property.